# "Double" doesn't get cast as "IComparable<Double>"

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have created a template that returns the index of the max value in an array. It works, but only if I pass in a weirdly cast List.

```
    static public int FindMaxIndex<T>( IEnumerable<IComparable<T>> arr )
    {
        IEnumerator<IComparable<T>> it = arr.GetEnumerator();
        if (!it.MoveNext()) return -1;
        int index = 1, maxIndex = 0;
        IComparable<T> max = it.Current;
        while (it.MoveNext())
        {
            if (max.CompareTo( (T)(it.Current) ) < 0)
            {
                maxIndex = index;
                max = it.Current;
            }
            ++index;
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
```

Now to use it:

```
    List<IComparable<Double>> arr = new List<IComparable<Double>>(); // THIS WORKS
    List<Double> arr = new List<Double>(); // THIS DOESN'T
```

The later list, which is what I would like to use, gives this compiler error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IComparable<double>>'
```

How can this be? "Double" IS an IComparable; taken from its definition:

`public struct Double : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<Double>, IEquatable<Double>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think other answers have addressed why your code as written [isn't working the way you'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981243/2779530) and even why the [code will fail in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981274/2779530).  However, none of the answers show you the way to do what you want:

```
public static int FindMaxIndex<T>( IEnumerable<T> source ) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    using( var e = source.GetEnumerator() )
    {
        if( !e.MoveNext() ) return -1;

        T maxValue = e.Current;
        int maxIndex = 0;

        for( int i = 1; e.MoveNext(); ++i )
        {
            if( maxValue.CompareTo( e.Current ) < 0 )
            {
                maxIndex = i;
                maxValue = e.Current;
            }
        }

        return maxIndex;
    }
}
```

So I've introduced a generic constraint here (the `where T : IComparable<T>`).  That tells the compiler that whatever `T` happens to be, it will implement `IComparable<T>`.

Also, I've put the enumerator in a `using` statement which will guarantee that its `Dispose` method is called.

Anyway, now when you call this method it will work directly on `IEnumerable<double>` and even deduce the type parameter for you:

```
var someDoubles = new List<double> { 3, 2, 1 };
Console.WriteLine( FindMaxIndex( someDoubles ) ) // Prints "0";
```

Also, if `FindMaxIndex` is declared in a `static` class, you can put the `this` keyword in front of the source parameter to make it an extension method:

```
public static int FindMaxIndex<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source ) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

Now you'll be able to call it like this:

```
list.FindMaxIndex()
```

Comment: @NuriTasdemir Yes, I saw that, that's why I left that as optional at the end.  There was nothing in OP's post that indicated it had to be.  Since they don't seem to know about generic constraints I assumed also that they didn't know about extension methods.

Comment: Love that for( int i = 1; e.MoveNext(); ++i ) loop. Neat.

Answer (score 3):

Generic covariance is only valid when the generic argument is a reference type.  Because you have a value type as the argument, it cannot perform any covariant conversions.

Comment: Code in question will fail if you use reference type instead of `double`, in the same way.

Comment: @Evk It compiles just fine on my machine when `Double` is a class.

Comment: My bad, was a problem on my side.

Comment: Irrelevant but... that's why I so much prefer C++ :-)

Answer (score 3):

`double` is an `IComparable<double>`, but `List<double>` is not a `List<IComparable<double>>`.

Nor could it be allowed to be. Consider:

```
private class ScrewItUp : IComparable<double>
{
    public int CompareTo(double value) => 0;
}

List<IComparable<double>> list = new List<double>(); // you propose that this work.
list.Add(new ScrewItUp()); // What's this supposed to do, then?
```

On can have variance involved in interfaces so that e.g. `List<string>` can be passed to `IEnumerable<object>` but that can only happen when the types involved in the variance are all reference types.

Comment: The OP is performing a conversion to `IEnumerable<IComparable<Double>>`, which is different, and can be covariant.

Comment: @Servy yes, I'd intended to mention that at the end, but then thought I'd mentioned it at the beginning, so was already adding that as you commented.

Answer (score -2):

[Jon Hanna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981274/1519458) is in the right direction. Below code works.

`double` may be a `IComparable<double>`. However a `List<double>` is not a `List<IComparable<double>>`. It is required to cast each element inside the list. You cannot cast whole list.

```
List<double> list = new List<double>() { 1,5,3};
Console.WriteLine(FindMaxIndex(list.Cast<IComparable<double>>()));
```

Comment: Why the downvotes, could you at least leave some comment?